# Eigenstates and Eigenvalues Problems in Quantum Mechanics (completeness/normalizable)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

A few questions bother me a lot when I read Griffith's book.

1. Are all associated Legendre functions $\{P_{\ell}^m(\cos \theta)\}$  complete for any function $f(\theta)$?
2. For the Hamiltonian of a Hydrogen atom, there are both bound states ($E<0$) and scattered states ($E>0$). If I only select all eigenfunctions of bound states, do they form a complete set for any function $f(r,\theta,\phi)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. More importantly, the spherical harmonics $Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)=Ne^{im\phi}P_l^m(\cos(\theta))$ (for some normalization $N$), are a "complete basis" for any function $f(\theta,\phi)$ (any function of $\theta$ and $\phi$ can be written as a sum of spherical harmonics). This can be proven with the spectral theorem (the same theorem that proves that eigenfunctions of a Hamiltonian are a basis for all wavefunctions). I'm not sure how familiar you are with the spectral theorem, but the basic components of the proof are this: the self-adjoint (Hermetian) operator is the $\theta,\phi$ derivatives in the Hamiltonian, and the inner product space is $\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}f_1^*(\theta,\phi)f_2(\theta,\phi)\sin\theta d\phi d\theta$.
   Perhaps you wanted to focus on $\phi$ symmetric wavefunctions, in which case $Y_l^0(\theta,\phi)=NP_l^0(\cos(\theta))$ are also a complete basis for functions of only $\theta$. You don't need all the different $m$ values.
2. NO, the bound states alone are not a complete Hilbert space - it is not generically true that any function $f(r,\theta,\phi)$ can be written as a sum of bound states. The spectral theorem only tells us that ALL the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian (not just the ones you like because they're normalizable) form a basis. Therefore, you need to also include the unbound states, which are frankly a pain to work with.

This is especially obvious when you consider a wavefunction which is a wavepacket of velocity $v$ very far from the nucleus. The potential energy is $0$ and the expectation value of kinetic energy is $mv^2/2$. So $\langle H\rangle=mv^2/2$. How could something with positive energy expectation value ever be written as a linear combination of wavefunctions which all have negative energy?

However, if you take the Hydrogen bound state wavefunctions and vary $Z$ (continuously from 0 to $\infty$), the nuclear charge, you do get a complete (obviously not orthogonal) set of wave functions which span the entire Hilbert space. This is useful in quantum chemistry for people who don't want to deal with non-normalizable wavefunctions in their calculations.

On a personal note, I learned this the hard way trying to calculate the groundstate energy of Helium by using linear combinations of tensor products of Hydrogen wavefunctions. The groundstate energy just refused to converge to the correct value, because part of the helium groundstate wavefunction does not overlap with the subset of the Hilbert space I was using.

Comment: I didn't know about the variation of Z trick. Would you say that that is a little bit (or even completely) like using a wavelet transform instead of a Fourier transform?